# Regex lookahead part of group accepted

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm using regex in powershell 5.1.

I need it to detect groups of numbers, but ignore groups followed or preceeded by /, so from this it should detect only 9876.

```
[regex]::matches('9876 1234/56',‘(?<!/)([0-9]{1,}(?!(\/[0-9])))’).value
```

As it is now, the result is:

9876

123

6

More examples: "13 17 10/20" should only match 13 and 17.

Tried using something like `(?!(\/([0-9]{1,})))`, but it did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?<!/)[0-9]+\b(?!/[0-9])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3c!%2f%29%5b0-9%5d%2b%5cb%28%3f!%2f%5cd%29&i=9876+1234%2f56%0d%0a13+17+10%2f20)

Alternatively, if the numbers can be glued to text:

```
(?<![/0-9])[0-9]+(?!/?[0-9])
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%2f0-9%5d%29%5b0-9%5d%2b%28%3f!%2f%3f%5b0-9%5d%29&i=9876+1234%2f56%0d%0a13+17+10%2f20).

The first pattern is based on word boundaries `\b` that make sure there are no letters, digits and `_` right before and after an expected match. The second one just makes sure there are no digits and `/` on both ends of the match.

**Details**

- `(?<![/0-9])` - a negative lookbehind making sure there is no digit or `/` immediately to the left of the current location
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digis
- `(?!/?[0-9])` - a negative lookahead making sure there is no optional `/` followed with a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am not that well versed in regular expressions, so I did not think of using \b.